# Looking up a local domain name without specifying the local DNS server

Tags: dns, bind

I've set up a local domain name by creating a zone (by following the steps in this [tutorial](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Host-Your-Own-Domain-With-Bind9-on-Ubuntu-49585.shtml)).

Why I look the domain using dig, I get the right results when using the following command:

```
dig debian.lan @localhost
```

But when I don't add the DNS address, it doesn't return an answer. How can I solve this problem?

```
dig debian.lan
```

Comment: What Unix variant or Linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` or whichever tool generates this file.

Comment: Do you mean adding nameserver 127.0.0.1 to it?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on setup, but as it is Debain I suspect you could add this line to
 `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

depending on your system `/etc/resolv.conf` most likely get overwritten.

Then restart `ethX` interface.

---

If you want to use `ifdown` and `ifup` you might also have to add this to your

`/etc/network/interfaces` (e.g. for `eth1`):

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Then first time reload:

```
sudo nohup sh -c "ifdown eth1 && ifup eth1"
```

---

If you are combining it with Apache add:

```
ServerName localhost
```

to:

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

to prevent *"apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified 
 domain name, …"* in your logs.

Comment: Thank you so much for you detailed answer. I couldn't vote it up since I don't have enough reputation yet :(